# Indicators do not accept mouse clicks

Tags: unity, indicator, panel

Since today the Unity systray icons for network, audio and messaging do not react on mouse clicks. Only data, me-menu and system-menu do react. When I open of them and move the mouse to the non-reacting icons they open. How can I fix or reset the Unity panel (indicator area)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing the "dconf-tools" from software center.

Press ALT + F2 to run a command and search for

dconf-editor

Highlight the whitelist entry as shown in the picture and click the Set To Default button.

[image]

- [How do I set the panel whitelist back to the default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76215/how-do-i-set-the-panel-whitelist-back-to-the-default)