# No response form top panel / menu on Samsung N150 Plus netbook

Tags: menu

I have an intermittent problem accessing the top panel/menu bar using the mouse in Ubuntu 11.04. sometimes I can access it with the mouse right click (as per normal), other times it is completely unresponsive whether using an external mouse of the mouse-pad. As I am new to Linux, I don't know if there is anyway to create a debug report or some other dump for the status of this menu. Its very irritating, especially when having to connect to a wifi network when on business but can't just right click and select the network. I ended up downloading WICF to manage my connections in a pop-up window but this is buggy too. I have the same set up on my desktop and the top menu/panel is accessible 100%, never fails. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: is it the whole panel or the indicators you have an issue with?  If its the indicators - have you playing with "whitelisting" applications?

Comment: Its just the default indicators on the top right which appear after the boot sequence. For example, if I use open truecrypt, the icon in the same location is accessible, its just the default ones which get locked.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the default indicator settings need to be reset.

Please look at [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40844/indicators-do-not-accept-mouse-clicks) and reset the indicator settings to their default settings.

Comment: I did as instructed on your link (my answer here) and rebooted. Default indicators came up first time - many thanks Foss.

Comment: Excellent news - if you feel that the answer is ok please "accept" the answer... an upvote would also be useful!