# Nothing happens when I click on Transmission's tray icon

Tags: indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indicators do not accept mouse clicks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40844/indicators-do-not-accept-mouse-clicks)

Normally a menu should pop up allowing me to show the program's window (it's minimized to tray), but when I click on the tray icon, nothing happens. This happens for almost all tray icons, I'm just using transmission as an example.

Answer (score 1):

This is [apparently not a bug in transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/3537).

Ubuntu have overridden the functionality. 
There is a "discussion" [in this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/transmission/+bug/524179).