# How do I undo the unity panel whitelist?

Tags: 12.04, unity, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the panel whitelist back to the default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76215/how-do-i-set-the-panel-whitelist-back-to-the-default)

Is there a way to remove this setting? I used it because a few things weren't showing up (indicators and such) and now everyone and they're grandmother shows up on the panel.

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"`